# Printer A5 paper feeder orientation

Tags: drivers, printing

All the A5 documents that I print assumes that the papers are fed in portrait mode in the printer feeder. Doesn't matter if I change the orientation in the page layout. It prints assuming portrait mode and some contents are cut if the paper is fed in landscape orientation. It does print EVERYTHING correctly if the paper is fed in portrait mode. I am trying to feed A5 papers in landscape mode for even wear on the toner. How to remedy this problem?

My printer model is Pantum M6550NW. The provided drivers are installed.

Comment: How many copies are you printing at a time? Have you tried printing A4 landscape mode? Please [edit] your question to include which package you are using to print as that may be significant. Also indicate your version of ubuntu

Comment: Yes, I am trying to print by feeding the papers in landscape orientation. Sorry, I am new to printing in linux environment and don't know about packages being used. The printer software seems to be named CUPS. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you using some software to generate the pages such as Libre Office for example? Your printer may use `Esc` codes which could change the orientation of the presented print. You'll find those in the printer manual.

Comment: Yes, I am using Libreoffice to generate the pages. One interesting phenomenon, If I export the files as PDF, they seem to be printed correctly(no change in page setup). That can be thought of as a solution I guess :p

Comment: whatever works for you is the solution.